# Can yarn add a package that is a devDependency as a global install?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I am adding a package to generate documentation to a node project with yarn.

It has a CLI, so will be doing a [global add](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global) `yarn global add my-package`

This package is a dev dependency, so when adding it to a project, used [-D to add as a devDependency](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add#toc-yarn-add-dev-d).

My understanding is that I will need to add it to the package with -D, since it isn't needed for the project to run and also to globally install it, to add it to my $PATH to be able to call it from the CLI.

Are these logically distinct and independent or is there such a thing as a global devDependency? Will the package.json end up in a state that will automatically globally install the tool for other developers' or pipeline environments?

Comment: You can use packages from cli by adding them to the scripts section in package.json

Comment: @Konrad this has taken me down a wonderful rabbit hole into how yarn builds its path https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run#toc-yarn-run-env https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/master/src/cli/commands/run.js

Answer (score 1):

Following [@Konrad's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76171572/can-yarn-add-a-package-that-is-a-devdependency-as-a-global-install?noredirect=1#comment134330274_76171572), to run a yarn package from the CLI, the appropriate method is to create a [yarn script in the package.json](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/package-json#toc-scripts) and [yarn run](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run#toc-yarn-run-script) it.

Running via `yarn run my-script` will add the node_modules to the $PATH that yarn uses when running.